# Would adding a PCI expansion card fix "not enough USB controller resources"?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I am having the rather annoying problem of whenever I add any new USB device to my computer I get an error that says "Not enough USB controller resources" and the device never initializes.

I have googled the problem and it seems ad though the Intel xHCI controller does not have enough available endpoints left to add the attached device (there is a lot plugged in).

So my question is thus: would adding a PCI card with more USB ports fix the problem? I am thinking that maybe the expansion card might come with its own controller and therefore more resources, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a problem if you get a card that simply fits into the pcie slot but wires into your motherboard (these used to come with some motherboards to add physical ports).

Any normal add on card, eg https://www.anker.com/products/68UPPCIE-4SU will have its own controller and driver. Just make sure your OS is supported.

Comment: I installed that card today and it fixed my problem almost plug-n-play. :) Just had to set the PCH to x1 in the BIOS.